# Trading View library implementation not supporting intraday candles

Tags: tradingview-api

I have an old (2018/2019) implementation of the Trading View library that I'm trying to fix. It only works in 1D (1 Day) or greater time frames, as the UI has greyed-out the shorter time periods.  However, my server is setup to handle 1 minute, 1 hour, and other periods.

I want to support these greyed out resolutions!

[image: greyed out time options]

http://www.campusactivism.org/predictit/pi/pi.php
And type in "2024 No" and select the first option to see some real data.

How can I get it to work for shorter time periods?

I'd rather not upgrade to the latest library - though if this is the only solution - I welcome comments (that aren't answers) on how to do this.

I've got "has_intraday" set to "true".  I think this setting handles this issue - but it doesn't seem to be working. Possibly my syntax is bad?

I had it working before in an earlier version, but I did something that broke it (and unfortunately I didn't use version control - so I cannot go back to the old one).  But I know that it is possible to have 1H resolution and others.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
    <title>TradingView Charting Library demo</title>

    <!-- Fix for iOS Safari zooming bug -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="charting_library/charting_library.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="datafeeds/udf/dist/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="datafeeds/udf/dist/bundle.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getParameterByName(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
            var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                    results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }

        TradingView.onready(function()
        {
            var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
                debug: true, // uncomment this line to see Library errors and warnings in the console
                fullscreen: true,
                //symbol: 'AAPL',
                //symbol: 'SAND.DNOM20',
                symbol: 'Enter your search term in the box in the upper left',
                //\\symbol: \'29462\',
                //symbol: '',

                //not sure why it doesn't let me use 29462...
                 //29462 --- WILL SWEDEN OR FINLAND TAKE FORMAL STEPS TO JOIN NATO IN 2022 WILL SWEDEN OR FINLAND TAKE FORMAL STEPS TO JOIN NATO IN 2022?
                
              allow_symbol_change: true,
                interval: '1D',
                container_id: "tv_chart_container",
                //  BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
                
                //can I use this type of url?
                //hmm should sort the markets by number or something - possibly descending - so you get the most recent ones first
                datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("http://www.campusactivism.org/predictit/server.php"),
                
                library_path: "charting_library/",
                locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",
                //  Regression Trend-related functionality is not implemented yet, so it's hidden for a while
                drawings_access: { type: 'black', tools: [ { name: "Regression Trend" } ] },
                disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
                //enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
                charts_storage_url: 'https://saveload.tradingview.com',
                charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
                client_id: 'tradingview.com',
                user_id: 'public_user_id',
                overrides: {'paneProperties.leftAxisProperties.autoScale':true, 
                                        'paneProperties.leftAxisProperties.autoScaleDisabled':false,
                                        'paneProperties.rightAxisProperties.autoScale':true, 
                                        'mainSeriesProperties.priceAxisProperties.autoScale':true,
                                        'mainSeriesProperties.priceAxisProperties.autoScaleDisabled':false
                                        

                }
                
                     
                
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="tv_chart_container"></div>
</body>
```

And for the server - it has this issue if I just use the default get_config function.

But I'm currently using:

```
function getconfig ()
{
  return '{
          "supports_group_request": true,
           "supported_resolutions": ["1", "3", "5", "15", "30", "60", "120", "240", "720", "1D", "3D", "1W", "2W", "4W"],
          "intraday_multipliers":  ["1", "3", "5", "15", "30", "60", "120", "240", "720", "1D", "3D", "1W", "2W", "4W"]
          }';
}
```